# TListView groups and items do not appear after clearing and reloading groups and items

Tags: delphi, tlistview

Delphi XE4 Update 1 and Windows 8.

When I add groups and items to the list view, they are displayed properly. When I then clear the items and groups, and add them again, nothing appears. Surely this is not the intended behavior?

From the DFM:

```
object lv: TListView
  Left = 24
  Top = 20
  Width = 250
  Height = 225
  Columns = <
    item
      Caption = 'Model'
      Width = 180
    end>
  GroupView = True
  ReadOnly = True
  RowSelect = True
  TabOrder = 0
  ViewStyle = vsReport
end
```

The code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LListGroup: TListGroup;
  LListItem: TListItem;
begin
  lv.Items.Clear;
  lv.Groups.Clear;

  LListGroup := lv.Groups.Add;
  LListGroup.Header := 'Ford';

  LListItem := lv.Items.Add;
  LListItem.Caption := 'Escape';
  LListItem.GroupID := LListGroup.ID;

  LListItem := lv.Items.Add;
  LListItem.Caption := 'F150';
  LListItem.GroupID := LListGroup.ID;

  OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('lv.Groups.Count=%d', [lv.Groups.Count])));
end;
```

The first time I click the button, the items appear and they're grouped.  The second time, the list view is blank.  If I comment out the line that clears the groups, then it works, but the number of groups, all of which are unused but one, grows by 1 each time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue with your code is which you are passing the `ID` property of the [`TCollectionItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.TCollectionItem) to the [`GroupID`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListItem.GroupID) property of the [`TListItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListItem) and you must use the [`GroupID`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListGroup.GroupID) property of the [`TListGroup`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListGroup).

So change this line

```
  LListItem.GroupID := LListGroup.ID; //here you are passing a wrong id for the group
```

to

```
  LListItem.GroupID := LListGroup.GroupID; //This is a valid assignment for the GroupID property
```

Comment: That was it! Totally obvious, but I can't tell you how many times I looked at it without seeing it. Thx.